# Add a line to a histogram to show the power law distribution in julia

Tags: julia, histogram, graph-theory, network-analysis, power-law

I have a value and plot a histogram like this (log-log scale):
[image]
The code for the histogram is as follows:

```
histogram(log.(degree), bins=50, yaxis = (:log10))
title!("Degree distribution (log-log scale)")
```

I want to add a line to the histogram to show it is a power law distribution. It will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `Plots.jl` you can just plot onto the previous plots (or more generally modify them) by adding a `!` to the command, so if you want do plot a line (or any other data) on top of a histogram you can do something like:

```
using Plots
a = rand(100)
histogram(a)
plot!([0,1],[5,25])
```

The other part is how to get the fit of the power law distribution, but I assumed that your problem is more about how to plot those things. Distributions.jl might help with the distribution fitting.